# How do I activate the "Product > Install" menu item in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos

In Xcode (7.3.1), there are key bindings for an "Install" menu item under the "Product" menu. They can be seen by opening Xcode's preferences, selecting the Key Bindings tab, and typing "Install" into the filter box.

[image: Key Bindings]

Presumably, these are related to the [build settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html), particularly `INSTALL_PATH`, which are used to control where the built application is placed if the build action is `install` (e.g., `xcodebuild install` from a command line).

However, while I can configure the values in my project such that `xcodebuild install` does what I want, I can't figure out how to get the "Install" menu option hinted at by the settings to ever appear.

I would expect that I need to edit one of my project schemes to configure it, but while I can see how to add new schemes, I can't seem to add a new action to the schemes (that is, the scheme editor only has categories for Build, Run, Test, Profile, Analyze and Archive. I can't get an "Install" item to appear there, either.

Is the "Product > Install" menu item just left over from earlier versions of Xcode and now unavailable, or is there some configuration trick I need to do to get it to show up?